# Как отправлять JSON данные вместе с файлом на PHP сервер?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, файлы, клиент-сервер

У меня есть клиентская часть в виде файла `profile.html` и серверная - `api.php`. Дело в том, что скрипт в `api.php` имеет много функций, поэтому для идентификации идёт приём с клиента данных формата JSON (пример: `{ "query": "profile_get_data" }`).
Я знаю, что у PHP есть $_FILES[ ] и пр. подобные глобальные переменные для фалов, но если я просто пошлю файл, то мне в ответ прилетит `{ "code":"1", "text": "Неизвестный запрос" }`. Поэтому на сервер помимо файла нужно отправить `{ "query": "avatar_upload" }` и сам файл. Подскажите, как я смогу реализовать эту функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одновременно отправить и JSON данные, и файл не получится, насколько я знаю.

Самый простой вариант - закодировать файл в base64  и положить в одно из полей JSON. На сервере, соответственно, воспользоваться функцией base64_decode.

Если нужно загружать именно файл, то придется модифицировать API, как вариант сделать GET-параметр, по которому api.php будет определять, что идет загрузка файла (?query=upload_file), либо сообще сделать отдельный ендпоинт (в вашем случае, видимо, отдельный файл вроде upload.php) для загрузки файлов.